# How do I loop through and add key values to values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, cheerio

I want to be able to loop through this object and add "key" values to the values so it can be easily used for a project. I'm Webscraping from a Website to get the data I have been able to get the data but I need to format it, here is my code and I'm stuck on what the next step is.

I'm trying to get it to look like this

**EXAMPLE**

- server: "USSouth2"
- cost: 100
- howmuch: 56
- time: 28

Code

```
let options = {
    url: 'https://www.realmeye.com/items/misc/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
    }
}
var result = [];
request(options, function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err) {

        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        let servers = $('.cheapest-server').attr('data-alternatives');

        servers.forEach(function(nexus) {
            result.push({
                servername: nexus[0],
                cost: nexus[1],
                howmuch: nexus[2],
                time: nexus[3]
            })
        })
    }
})
```

JSON object (this can change depending on the Website data)

```
["USSouth2 Nexus",100,56,28],["EUSouth Nexus",100,62,25],["AsiaSouthEast Nexus",100,58,25],["EUNorth2 Nexus",100,64,24],["EUEast Nexus",100,55,24],["USWest2 Nexus",100,73,23],["USMidWest2 Nexus",100,53,21],["USEast2 Nexus",100,98,17],["EUWest Nexus",100,66,11],["EUSouthWest Nexus",100,86,10],["USNorthWest Nexus",100,87,9],["USSouthWest Nexus",100,67,9],["EUWest2 Nexus",100,89,8],["USWest Nexus",100,66,8],["USSouth Nexus",100,54,7],["USMidWest Nexus",100,90,6],["USSouth3 Nexus",100,82,6],["USEast Nexus",100,65,1]]
```

I'm getting this error
`TypeError: servers.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Where is `nexus` coming from?

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML that you're trying to get the list of `servers` from?  We need to see that so we can properly advise on how to use cheerio to get that.  It may just be that you're getting a string and you need to parse it into an array or perhaps you aren't using cheerio properly. We need to see the actual HTML you're trying to get data from in order to know.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - It's supposed to be coming from the HTML (but that isn't working properly).  See `nexus` in `servers.forEach(function(nexus) {`

Comment: Hi, please look at the answer I have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it I forgot to parse the JSON here is the answer by making a new variable

`let jsonData = JSON.parse(servers);`

Comment: Great but still you need to check first of array length

Answer (score 0):

I haev updated the code snippet. please check now.

```js
    let servers = [["USSouth2 Nexus",100,56,28],["EUSouth Nexus",100,62,25],["AsiaSouthEast Nexus",100,58,25],["EUNorth2 Nexus",100,64,24],["EUEast Nexus",100,55,24],["USWest2 Nexus",100,73,23],["USMidWest2 Nexus",100,53,21],["USEast2 Nexus",100,98,17],["EUWest Nexus",100,66,11],["EUSouthWest Nexus",100,86,10],["USNorthWest Nexus",100,87,9],["USSouthWest Nexus",100,67,9],["EUWest2 Nexus",100,89,8],["USWest Nexus",100,66,8],["USSouth Nexus",100,54,7],["USMidWest Nexus",100,90,6],["USSouth3 Nexus",100,82,6],["USEast Nexus",100,65,1]];

    var result = [];

    servers.forEach(function(nexus) {
                result.push({
                    servername: nexus[0],
                    cost: nexus[1],
                    howmuch: nexus[2],
                    time: nexus[3]
                });
            });
            
            console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry I think I made the post a bit unclear, I've updated it now

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the problem the OP has.  The OP is trying to get some data from some parsed HTML and then iterate over a list of items from that HTML.

Comment: he mentioned something else earlier and based on that , I have provided solution. Now he has changed his question, as you can read from his comment" . so there is no need of negative voting.

Comment: Ask I can't mark my own answer this is close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if you know for sure the four keys will not change, then do something like this.

Create an array with the four keys in order of appearance in a single JSON array value. Use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of the array to loop over the array and manipulate each value and the and the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to turn an array into object.

Check out the example below to see what it does.

```js
// Your JSON.
const json = [["USSouth2 Nexus",100,56,28], ["EUSouth Nexus",100,62,25]];

// The four keys of the object. In order of the JSON array.
const keys = ['servername', 'cost', 'howmuch', 'time'];

// Loop over servers and return an object reduces from an array.
const servers = json.map(server =>
  server.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
      let key = keys[i];
      acc[key]= cur;
      return acc;
  }, {}));

console.log(servers);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check is servers are prsent and it's in form of array anf if so, then loop through the servers and get your data

```
const servers = $('.cheapest-server').attr('data-alternatives');

if (servers && Array.isArray(servers) && servers.length) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < servers.lenght; i += 1) {
    const entity = servers[i];
    const objBuilder = {
      servername: entity[0] || null,
      cost: entity[1] || null,
      howmuch: entity[2] || null,
      time: entity[3] || null,
    };  
    result.push(objBuilder);
  }
} else {
  // Error handling or pass an empty array
}
```